# What are some good resources to understand Hierarchical Statistical Models like Mixed Models?

Tags: mixed-model

The problem I am working on not only requires me to use several levels but also identify, from a set of attributes, which ones could be treated as levels.

What is a good resource to understand Mixed Models? Also, what are the concepts that one must understand before putting such models to use? And what are other models that could be useful to in such hierarchical setting.

Comment: I would recommend the great book [Hierarchical Linear Models: Applications and Data Analysis Methods](http://books.google.com/books?id=uyCV0CNGDLQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Raudenbush and Bryk.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a book, I'd suggest you take a look at Gelman & Hill's [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X) at Amazon to see if it suits your needs. (There are some additional resources at their [website](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/).) It may not be what you want/need, but it's worth a look.